# MAC-Xcode not available

Tags: macos

i am using mac 10.7.3.I have installed Xcode.when i restart or shutdown the system that Xcode is not available.i am new to mac.please somebody help to solve this problem

Comment: What do you mean by "not available"? What does App Store say (is it marked as installed?

Comment: i could not find when i search for it..to open my project i need to re install Xcode

Comment: how do i know whether it is installed or not?..

Comment: Open App Store, search for XCode, and there is either a "Download" or an "Installed" button.

Comment: which version of Xcode suitable for mac 10.7.3?..

Comment: thanking you for answering..i found solution for my problem.